# OneClassSVM for binary classification

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm, multiclass-classification

I am using OneClassSVM for a binary classification problem. I have a dataset where the target variable is labeled 0 or 1. I don't know if OneClassSVM can be used for binary or multi classification problems, but when I try to predict I get the following:
**y_true:**

```
[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
```

**y_pred:**

```
[-1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1
  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

There are many -1 values in the **y_pred** I assume these are the instances where the model was trying to predict the class 0 but could not ?

**Main Question:** can OneClassSVM be used for binary classification ?

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains well:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99162/what-is-one-class-svm-and-how-does-it-work

To summarize, if your task is to perform a binary classification simply you should employ `sklearn.svm.SVC`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of 1 and 0, your output is just 1 and -1.